# How to get rid of acne marks and scars?

Tags: dermatology, acne

I have had acne for 2 years now. I used to have acne everywhere on my face and even on my spine. Recently I stopped eating junk food and chocolate, small breakouts that come and go from time to time.

My main problem now is red and purple acne marks.I drink 3-4 cups of Lipton green tea to help prevent acne. Yesterday I started drinking lemon juice with sugar and water for vitamin C, so far there is no result. I have tried various treatments to help with marks, but so far nothing is helping.

Here is the image of my scars: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTtdO.jpg

Comment: If you are trying to avoid future breakouts I'm not sure if sugar water is a good choice. You might want to do a little more research on that. Good luck!

Comment: @EricaGrant even with lemon? It's hard to drink lemon juice without sugar

Comment: I'm not sure that technique is the most efficient way to increase your vitamin C levels. You should be able to increase your vitamin C levels by eating more whole foods that are rich in vitamin C or adding a vitamin C supplement to your diet: https://draxe.com/vitamin-c-foods/

Comment: I'm not sure if the picture shows acne scars and marks. At least some of those spots are probably active acne papules. I believe, acne are triggered by stress. Merely reducing stress, even for a bit, such as by having regular sleep, avoiding too much foods you feel they are not good for you and concentrating on work you feel is right for you, can  help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: many therapies can reduce acne scars, but no therapy can get rid of acne scars entirely, so you should talk to a dermatologist about the best option for you.

The long answer: Preventing acne scars in the first place is the best approach, but there are many methods for removing scars of different types. There are different kinds of acne scars: atrophic scars (indentations in the skin caused by destruction and loss of collagen), and hypertrophic scars and keloids (firm, raised lump; less common; caused by collagen gain). There may also be a reddish hue associated with either type of acne scar. The first step in treating acne scars is to treat the redness. The best treatment to decrease redness is pulsed-dye laser therapy, which targets oxyhemoglobin (a compound from blood) within the skin and can reduce redness by about 60%. Other steps in treating acne scars include the CROSS technique (chemical reconstruction of skin scars, using a trichloroacetic acid peel), subcision (a surgical technique), and punch excision and punch elevation (another surgical technique). Collagen remodeling procedures are also available, which include ablative laser resurfacing, a method that ablates parts of the skin very precisely. Other miscellaneous acne scar treatments: chemical peels, dermabrasion, skin needling, injectable soft tissue fillers, and silicone gel sheeting. NOTE: Do not try any of the medical procedures at home. Talk to an experienced dermatologist. The best way for you to reduce the appearance of your acne scars will be to meet with a dermatologist who can give you a physical exam, treat any ongoing acne flare-ups, and provide you with personalized, practical options for reducing your existing acne scarring. Reference: "Management of Acne Scars" from the UpToDate encyclopedia; article written by Nazanin Saedi MD and Nathan Uebelhoer MD.